# For Windows App using PhoneGap, how to achieve a file download and open

Tags: cordova

I am creating a Windows App using PhoneGap. I am facing problem with downloading a file and opening it. I am using FileTransfer, and am able to successfully download the file, but could not locate the file to open. when I search the file in File Explorer, I do not see any downloaded file.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us the code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.